# SQL - searching with one against many conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out how to get better performance when filtering Table.
In my specific situation, I am filtering location table which have columns for Google geolocation (route, street_number, city, country and so on).

Now, all this values are in separate columns, and I can simply filter with multiple conditions, but I am interested how this multiple conditions effect search ?

Would it be better to search for full address with all params in 1 field or to search for each field separately ?

For example, is it better to filter with Q1:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE route='some route' AND street_number='x' AND country='xy'
```

or Q2:

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE full_route='some route x, xy'
```

Of course in this other situation I need to have standard for connecting those strings into one.

Generally speaking, is it better to search with more conditions or only with one ?

Comment: I'm assuming the difference will be negligible, but you can try running some of your own tests with some loops.  However, I would stick to `Q1` because of readability.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, `full_route` should not be a column in the database at all, since it merely duplicates data already found in route, street_number, and country.

Comment: Sam, thanks for answer, I'll definitely do some test.
Chris, it shouldn't, but if it would enabled me much faster search I would denormalize table for it. In this case performance is more important to me then normalization and size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that multiple columns is best. You can index less data ( like indexing `country` ) and SQL has better performance with searching the number as an `INT` instead of searching it as a part of an `varchar`
And BTW, if you make it a single `varchar` collumn you are also prone to have problems with whitespaces

**EDIT:**
With multiple collumns you can also turn *common* places as foreign keys ( in this case, the `country` collumn ). That can improve speed ( because it will be indexed ) and save disk space (as it will be only an `INT` instead of a `varchar` for each address row)

**AND** if you use some class to manage your DataBase connection ( such as Doctrine in PHP ), it can cache the `country` table on memory, to get the `country` as an `int` and then do the SQL search. That would improve performance a lot ;)

Comment: You are welcome. If you are using _PHP_ on a _VPS_, i would recommend using **Doctrine**. It has an overhead on performance as it includes lots of classes and functions. But it may make queries faster when caching to memory the most used rows/queries/entities. Good luck!  
**EDIT** Link is http://www.doctrine-project.org/